# "lying on his face" vs "lying on one's stomach"

Tags: english-to-german

There are two questions here.

> He is lying on his face/stomach.

1) Can the phrases "on one's stomach" and "on one's face" be deemed as interchangeable? They seem semantically same (being on the same side of the body) but I still feel they must be different somehow.

2) How would we translate these phrases in German? I found "bäuchlings" for the stomach part, but there doesn't seem to be a translation for the former. Is the literal translation of "auf dem Gesicht" appropriate? Physically, my face is *below* me, so a literal approach seems shady to me.

Help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> He is lying on his stomach. = Er liegt auf dem Bauch.

...e.g. when he is sleeping.

> He is lying on his face. = Er liegt mit dem Gesicht nach unten.

... e.g. after he had an accident and is unconscious now.

The literal translation *Er liegt auf dem Gesicht.* is not common, although maybe you could use it in colloquial speech. But since the face is not "supporting" the body, it sounds rather strange.

Anyway bit more context is necessary to judge whether it can actually be used interchangeably.

Comment: I agree, `Er liegt auf dem Gesicht` sounds a bit like he fell and hit the ground with his face.

Answer (score 3):

If someone should lie face down, you could say:

> - mit dem Gesicht nach unten legen (vs.: mit dem Gesicht nach oben legen)
> - auf den Bauch legen (vs.: auf den Rücken legen)
> - bäuchlings hinlegen (vs.: rücklings hinlegen)

Comment: Wunderbar! Jetzt habe ich noch mehre Methoden, indem ich kann ja einschlafen.

Answer (score 1):

Deine Frage scheint aus dem Englischen zu kommen, wobei wir ja dafür keine Experten sind. Sagt man im Englischen wirklich "stomach", wenn man von auf dem Bauch liegen spricht? Ich hätte mit waist oder body gerechnet.

So oder so gibt es im Deutschen die Redewendung

> etwas liegt mir auf dem Magen

wobei in der Tat nur Magen, nicht Bauch verwendet werden kann, und es immer etwas, nicht jemand ist, was auf dem Magen liegt (evtl. zur Verstärkung schwer auf dem Magen liegt), und womit ein Problem, eine Sorge bezeichnet wird.

Selbst wenn man auf dem Bauch liegt dreht man aber das Gesicht zur Seite - zumindest habe ich noch nie abweichendes beobachtet, außer bei der Gymnastik vielleicht. Sich auf 's Gesicht legen klingt sonst recht befremdlich.

Comment: Man sagt (in Amerika) tatsächlich *"stomach"* - besser ist allerdings auch dort *"to lie face down"*.